# Problem with curl, xpath query

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

I need some help with my xpath query.  I can get this code to work with just about every site I need to scrape except this small part of a particular site...  I just get a blank page...  Does anyone have an idea on how I can do this better?

```
//
$target_url = "http://www.teambuy.ca/vancouver/";
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';

// make the cURL request to $target_url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$html= curl_exec($ch);
if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}

// parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body/div[@id='pagewrap']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='bottomSection']/div[@id='bottomRight']/div[@id='sideDeal']/div[2]/div/a/center/span");

foreach ($hrefs as $e) {
    $e->nodeValue;
}
$insert = $e->nodeValue;
echo "$insert";
```

**--EDIT--**

No luck...
Fatal error: Call to a member function loadHTMLfile() on a non-object in ... Line 4
     //

```
$xpath_query = $dom->loadHTMLfile("http://www.teambuy.ca/vancouver/");

$hrefs = $xpath_query->evaluate("/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/center/span");

foreach ($hrefs as $e) {
    echo $e->nodeValue;
}
$insert = $e->nodeValue;

echo "$insert";
```

Comment: $userAgent is being ignored, although that's probably not your error.

Comment: You are not saying what site fails, and what happens when you try to call that site - there's probably nothing anybody can do for you

Comment: Also, `$insert` is undefined.

Comment: $target_url = "http://www.teambuy.ca/calgary/"

Comment: There is no <div id="sideDeal">. You should actually look at the source and find what it is you are looking for, then build an xpath from that.

Comment: I really screwed this up...  Try $target_url = "teambuy.ca/vancouver/";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use cURL. just use

```
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.teambuy.ca/calgary/");
```

don't use

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

just use

```
$href = $dom->xpath($xpath_query);
```

I imagine your xpath query could be simplified as well...

also,

```
foreach ($hrefs as $e) {
    $e->nodeValue;
}
```

does nothing. might want to try this instead.

```
foreach ($hrefs as $e) {
    echo $e->nodeValue;
}
```